# Symfony 6.1 - The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application

Tags: php, symfony

When converting my Symfony 3.3 project to Symfony 6.1 I came across a problem related to the bundles/securitybundle.

The exception which I'm getting;

```
     The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle"
```

But I confirmed that symfony/security-bundle is installed.

I'm using MicroKernel. My services.yaml is the following;

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true


    App\Controller\AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/AppBundle/Controller/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/Controller/AppBundle/Controller/ConsultantCompare/Processor.php'

        calls:
            - [ 'setContainer', [ '@service_container' ] ]
```

Bundles.php;

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Did I not register the bundle correctly?

**Edit;**

It is not just the Security bundle, also other bundles like twig give the same exception;

```
You cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig Bundle is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle".
```

Comment: 3.3 to 6.1 is quite a jump.  Not saying don't do it but it can be challenging.  For example the service_container service is no longer defined by default and the container used by controllers have been replaced with a service locator.  I'd suggest creating a new 6.1 project just to get an idea what a working project looks like.  Then install any third party bundles you might be using just to confirm they have a version that works on 6.1.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! @Cerad

I was wondering; is injection the only way of making something available in all Controllers? Or is there a way such that I can do this->container to get for instance the entitymanager everywhere?

Comment: If you do decide to make the jump to 6.1, try looking into [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) for automatic upgrades. It doesn't work flawless, but might save you a lot of time as it did me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error going from Symfony 5 to 6 in some of my reusable bundles. My controller service definitions in those bundles looked like this:

```yaml
MyBundle\Controller\MyController:
    tags: ["controller.service_arguments"]
    calls:
        - method: setContainer
          arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

I figured out I needed to change the definition to this:

```yaml
MyBundle\Controller\MyController:
    tags: ["container.service_subscriber", "controller.service_arguments"]
    autowire: true
```